# Only one group will expand in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am new to Android development. I followed [this](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) tutorial for showing `ExpandableListView` and its working properly. If I press all group then all group will expand.

I want to expand only one group at a time. At the beginning, the first group will expand automatically and If I tap another group then the first group will collapse and the recent group will expand. Is it possible?

If possible then how can I get. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may achieve using `GroupExpandListener`.Store last Expanded position to variable and collapseGroup using this variable

```
private int lastPosition = -1;
private ExpandableListView lv; //your expandable listview

lv.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if (lastPosition != -1
                    && groupPosition != lastPosition) {
                lv.collapseGroup(lastPosition);
            }
            lastPosition = groupPosition;
    }
});
```